# keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format - Android

Tags: android, keystore

I was following Step 3 from https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/get-started but I entered the wrong keystore password and now I am getting a "Invalid keystore format". Please advise how to fix? Here's the full stacktrace:

```
mymacbook .android $ keytool -exportcert -alias \
> androiddebugkey -keystore \
> ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v
Enter keystore password:  
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:780)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:889)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:340)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:333)
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:778)
    ... 7 more
mymacbook .android $ keytool -exportcert -alias \
> > androiddebugkey -keystore \
> > ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v
mymacbook .android $ keytool -exportcert -alias \
> androiddebugkey -keystore \
> ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:658)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:792)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:340)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:333)
mymacbook .android $
```

And now whenever I type the following command I just keep getting the "invalid keystore format" error and it doesn't even ask me to enter password now:

"keytool -exportcert -alias \
androiddebugkey -keystore \
~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v"

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are passing "android" password (make sure you are using small letters).

Comment: thanks but it won't even ask me for password now as I get the Invalid Keystore format

Comment: What about those two lines: "> ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v
Enter keystore password:"?

Comment: Actually, that was when I entered  the password incorrectly the first time and now this keeps happening. When I type the command " keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v" it does not ask me for a password ever again because i get that error

Comment: Try removing the old debug keystore. After deleting, regenerate it in Android Studio.

Comment: remove you mean delete it completely? Please elaborate how do I regenerate it back using Android Studio?

Comment: Yes, delete (you can always make a backup if you need) the file. Android studio will generate new debug certificate when you try to make debug build again.